# VLC - how to show FPS

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, vlc-media-player

Is there any standard way in VLC to show FPS ?

Comment: For Windows see this https://superuser.com/questions/1188897/how-do-i-see-the-fps-of-playback-in-vlc-and-other-video-players-in-windows/1188898#1188898

Answer (score 7):

If by FPS you mean the frame rate at which a video is played, you can access that information while playing by clicking on Tools >>> Codec information.
In the video stream there should be a row with that information. (I'm basing myself on a Windows 2.0.2 version but it should also be valid for any other GUI).

If on the other hand you're looking for a overlaid FPS display I believe VLC doesn't do that, as mentioned before, but there should be some third party solutions.

Comment: Ctrl+J is the keyboard shortcut

Comment: There is no frame rate row for .webm files :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the fps counter because you suspect the VLC is dropping frames, you can see the lost/dropped video frames and audio blocks in statistic tab. You can also see the input bitrate graph, content bitrate, demuxed data size and more.

Go to:

1. Tools
2. Media Information (ctrl-j for shortcut)
3. Statistics

You can also use MPV to see statistics of the playing video with I keyboard [short-cut](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#stats). Because MPV has less GUI you probably will get better fps and CPU usage.