# How do I see the FPS of playback in VLC and other video players in windows?

Tags: media-player, benchmarking, fps

I play animated videos and notice a lag or frame drop.

I learned later that this is due to Japanese anime being not fully animated due to low budgets.

But I want to be sure. Nvidia Geforce FPS overlay is not working for Video players.

Is there a program to show FPS of video playback in VLC and other players?

Answer (score 0):

Try Fraps. It works with video and graphic sources that don't work with other FPS overlay programs.

[image: Fraps overlay setting]

I tested it with VLC and the framerate is constant 24 FPS. It seems that the poor animation is the cause of my concern and not my PC.
[image: Fraps FPS overlay in the top-right corner]

Comment: Doesn't VLC have a native feature?

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1188898/34985) was posted nearly a year before [the release of VideoLAN 3.0.0](https://www.videolan.org/news.html#news-2018-02-09) (2018-02-09).  According to [this forum post](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=493939#p493939)...

> Fraps doesn't work for me with vlc 3.0.x. No overlay, no recording, no screen capture.

...and my experience is the same with v3.0.16: there is no overlay and the CSV logs indicate something like 1 frame/second.  I tried the workaround posted in [the reply](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=512100#p512100)...

> ... I got them to work together by changing video output module in VLC to 'OpenGL video output for Windows' (Preferences > show settings: All > Video > Output modules > Video output module)

...and while that did succeed in making `Fraps`'s overlay appear, that alternately caused poor performance or screen artifacts.

Instead, [on AlternativeTo I found](https://alternativeto.net/software/fraps/) a tool called [`FPS Monitor`](https://fpsmon.com/) that lets you monitor various system components with a customizable screen overlay.  Even in trial mode I was able to use it to monitor the playback framerate in `VLC`.  The one thing that tripped me up, however, is that `VLC media player` **must** be started *after* `FPS Monitor`; it's not enough to just stop and restart video playback.  Other than that, I was able to get not only numbers but a live graph of the information I was looking for (`Scenes` → `Recent scenes` → `BENCHMARK` is a good preset to use).  Neat.